# Spring ExitCodeEvent using @EventListener not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am trying to catch the event code at the time my springboot app is destroyed. I have the following bean:

```
@Configuration
public class DestroyListenerConfig {

    @Bean
    DemoListener demoListenerBean() {
        return new DemoListener();
    }

    private static class DemoListener {
        @EventListener
        public void exitEvent(ExitCodeEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Exit code: " + event.getExitCode());
        }
    }
}
```

The bean is registering properly, but when I kill the application, the exitEvent() method is not invoked ( the system out never displays, or when run in debug mode from IDE, it never enters the method).

Am I leaving something out? My impression was this is all that is needed. Thanks.

Comment: how do u kill the application?

Answer (score 0):

**ExitCodeEvent is published from org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication#exit.** So, you need to manually call SpringApplication.exit as below.

```
@Autowired
ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@GetMapping("/shutdown")
void shutdown() {
    SpringApplication.exit(applicationContext, () -> 100);
}
```

**If you want to listen to a bean destroy event then you can use @PreDestroy as following:**

Note that if you have multiple beans created for this class, you will get multiple triggers.

```
//Put this into a @Component(or inside RestController, Controller, Service etc) class

@javax.annotation.PreDestroy
public void destroy() {
    System.out.println("Triggered - @PreDestroy.");
}
```

**If your app is a webapp and you want to listen to shutdown event (ideally the contextDestroyed event) you can register a MyServletContextListener to ServletListenerRegistrationBean:**

```
    @Bean
    ServletListenerRegistrationBean<ServletContextListener> servletListener() {
        ServletListenerRegistrationBean<ServletContextListener> srb = new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<>();
        srb.setListener(new MyServletContextListener());
        return srb;
    }

class MyServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Callback triggered - ContextListener.");
    }
}
```

Ref:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.java#L1332

Comment: this will work - but it's not necessarily what he asks for. He wants to listen for context destroyed event, not destruction of the bean (which is result of shutting down the spring context)

Comment: You are right about the bean destroy. I updated my answer to show an example of callback for Context Destroyed event

Comment: @gtiwari333, thanks for your response. I was hoping to be able to intercept an actual "code" returned. I currently have the PreDestroy implemented which works fine, its just that I was hoping to get that code.